# Ruby, extract keys and values and then create an array of array for keys and values

Tags: ruby, arrays, key

I want to extract the keys and values from an array to create two arrays in array, one containing the keys and the other the values:

keysAndValues({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}) # should return [[:a, :b, :c], [1, 2, 3]]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def keysAndValues(hsh)
  [hsh.keys, hsh.values]
end

keysAndValues {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
# => [[:a, :b, :c], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def keys_and_values(hash)
  hash.to_a.transpose
end
```